# How can i change img only on the tag on hover in react?

Tags: reactjs

I would like to change the img only on the tag on hover.
Find a way... but not the best one, how to simplify please ?

here my code

```
function Main(props) {

    const [change, setChange] = useState(0);
    const [change1, setChange1] = useState(0);

    function changeOver() {
        setChange(1)
    }

    function changeOut() {
        setChange(0)
    }

    function changeOver1() {
        setChange1(1)
    }

    function changeOut1() {
        setChange1(0)
    }
 return (
    <section className="test2">
        <div className="navbar">
            <a href="#" onMouseEnter={changeOver} onMouseLeave={changeOut}>
                <span>Végétarien </span> 
                <img src={change ? vegeColor : vege } style={{ height: '1.8em' }}/>
            </a>
            <a href="#" onMouseEnter={changeOver1} onMouseLeave={changeOut1}>
                <span>Poisson </span>
                <img src={change1 ? seafoodColor : seafood } style={{ height: '1.8em' }} />
            </a>
    </section>
            
        )
}
```

any advices please

Comment: I don't know if it is the more elegant solution but you can put the image as an image background and change it easily with css

Comment: try event `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` .

Comment: thx gonna try it

Comment: Ok thx ! Have another question... i update my code